# Is it better to pay \$1 today or \$1 tomorrow?

Tags: interest-rates

I get from the time value of money that receiving \$1 today is worth more than receiving \$1 tomorrow. But what about paying money, as opposed to getting money. Do i prefer to pay \$1 tomorrow than today, because that same \$1 tomorrow would be worth <\$1 today? Or do i prefer benefits and costs today rather than tomorrow?

edit: Assuming no inflation, as to not complicate matters. No uncertainty at all about future prices.

Comment: Yes, if you have a choice you prefer to pay later. You want to increase the value of what you receive and reduce the value of what you pay.